# How to solve an error when trying to create tables using the menu and the right button in the mouse in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

My problem is this: when I try to create a table in SQL Server database using the right click button in the mouse and then choosing "New > Table", an error message appears

> This back-end version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)

I tried downloading the Database Tools but still the same error message appears.

Any ideas?

Thank you all!

Comment: What version you are using? Use select @@version to know the SQL server version.

Comment: I am using 2014 SQL Server 14.0.2002

Comment: Build 14.0.2002 of SQL Server is actually SQL Server 2017. See [MS Support Page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321185/how-to-determine-the-version-edition-and-update-level-of-sql-server-an) on build numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It normally happens when the database version is newer than the database Tool you are using.
Its always better to use a newer version of SSMS or datatools than the database

Answer (score 0):

I also have the similar question.

When I use the SQL Server Management Studio 2014 to connect to the SQL Server 2017 and right click "New -> Table" the error appears.

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHroW.png)

But if I use the SSMS 2014 to connect the SQL Server 2012 and also right click "New -> Table", the table design page occurs normally.

It is not suggested to do operations via using the GUI for SSMS which version is earlier than SQL Server.

As workarounds:

```
1. please use the T_SQL to execute operations instead of GUI. 
2. please use the matched or higher versions for SSMS.
```

By the way, from SQL Server 2016, SSMS is not installed along with SQL Server. You can download the latest SSMS separately from the link.

[Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)